# Function with Variable length argument

Tags: c

I have following question on function with Variable length argument in C:

**Case 1** (Works)

```
myPrintf("%d %s", 24, "Hi There");
```

**Case 2** (Works)

```
char tempbuf[9]="Hi There";`
myPrintf("%s %d", tempbuf, 24)
```

**Case 3** (Doesn't work)

```
myPrintf("%s %d", "Hi There", 24)
```

Does anyone has any idea why the case 3 doesn't work. I could see `str = va_arg(ap, char *);` returning `24` for this case intead of the actual string.

Code for myPrintf:
(It is not fully functional though)

```
void myPrintf(char *fmt, ...)
{
int i,j,val,len;
char *str;
int len2;
va_list ap;
char tempBuf[128];

len=strlen(fmt);

memset(tempBuf,0,MAX_MSZ_LEN);

va_start(ap,fmt);

for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{
switch(fmt[i])
{
  case '%' :
  i++;
  if( fmt[i] == 's' )
  {
    str = va_arg(ap, char *);
    strcat(tempBuf, str);
  }
  else
    if( fmt[i]=='i' || fmt[i]=='d' )
    {
      val=va_arg(ap,int);
      sprintf(str,"%d",val);
      strcat(tempBuf, str);
    }
  default : 
  len2=strlen(tempBuf);
  tempBuf[len2]=fmt[i];
  }
}
va_end(ap);
}
```

}

Comment: What's the code for `myPrintf()`?

Comment: We'll need to see the code for `myPrintf` to offer much help - it looks like a sensible code fragment so far.

Comment: Do you have any code for myprintf?

Comment: What's the difference between `myPrintf` and `myprintf` for that matter?

Comment: what's the code for `myprintf()` and `myPrintf()` ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the comma after the format string in case 3?

Comment: As @casablanca says you are using an uninitialized variable: `str`; and there's no `break` for your `case '%'` label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case for `%d`:

```
sprintf(str,"%d",val);
```

what does `str` point to? If there was a `%s` earlier, it points to one of the format arguments, otherwise it is uninitialized -- in both cases, it points to an invalid location for writing. You need another temporary buffer to write the value into. You were just lucky that cases 1 and 2 worked.

Comment: @Punit: When `%d` is before `%s`, `str` is uninitialized -- you were just lucky it worked, it could have very well crashed. With `%d` after `%s`, when you used a character array for "Hi There", you could technically modify it because you allocated space for it. When you pass "Hi There" directly, it's a `const` string, so you can't write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code:

```
   if( fmt[i]=='i' || fmt[i]=='d' )
    {
      val=va_arg(ap,int);
      sprintf(str,"%d",val);
      strcat(tempBuf, str);
    }
```

The sprintf() call there is trying to write something to `str`. What is str ? 
When you call it like `myPrintf("%s %d", "Hi There", 24)` , the `str` will be the 2. argument, the string "Hi There". You cannot change a string literal in C, this will likely fail and might cause a crash.

When you call it like `myPrintf("%s %d", tempbuf, 24)`, `str` will be `tmpbuf`, which is an array, which you can write to so that's fine. It only holds room for 9 bytes though, so it's easy to overflow that buffer.

You should rather just do something like

```
      char tmp[32];
      sprintf(tmp,"%d",val);
      strcat(tempBuf, tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb... Put a comma after the format string for case 3.

Comment: I'm guessing your real code is missing the comma: myPrintf("%s %d" "Hi There", 24); and the strings are getting concatenated.